# Facebook login IP list

Tags: facebook, security

Is it possible on Facebook to obtain a list of recent login IP addresses? If not, is it possible to get information about recent login attempts?

When somebody tries to login (but fails the photo verification) the owner is alerted by a popup at login time (login attempt). How can (s)he view the info showed by that popup once again?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools in the [Security settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security) tab which should be helpful:

- **Login Alerts** lets you get notifications via email and/or text message when there is a login to your account from a new device.
- **Login Approvals**, if turned on, sends an access code via SMS that you need to enter when logging in from a new device.
- **Where You're Logged In** shows the browser (or client), OS, and approximate location that Facebook has you logged in.You can click "End Activity" to log out any of these devices. Unfortunately, it doesn't give IP addresses.

Comment: You can view the IP: move the mouse above the location. The geolocator it uses is not the best. As far as I know, it is also unable to provide recent logins IP list.

Comment: Login alerts are also tricky: it sent me no alert when signing in with a weird new user agent from a proxy IP.